# How to replace "[X]" in a string with a particular value for each X?

Tags: c#, string

```
string Sample=@"
Select * from Table1 where Id =[MY Id]
and Column2=[MY Column2 Value]
 ";
```

This is SqlCommand CommandText I will replace all string that start with [ and end with ]
before use command
How Can I find parameter name beetwen [ and ] ?
Do I have to use string.IndexOf (Sample,'[') ets. or Is there another void to make easy?

Comment: Why not create the sql once you know the values?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the standard sql parameters approach for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the possibility of using `SqlParameter`, you can define

```
string Sample=@"
Select * from Table1 where Id =[{0}]
and Column2=[{1}]
 ";
```

and then obtain the command as

```
string cmd = String.Format(Sample, id1, id2);
```

where `id1` and `id2` are your parameters.

Comment: This method is open to SQL injection. Don't do this. @BrokenGlass's solution is better because it uses parameterized queries.

Comment: I agree, but the OP formulated this as a string question. I also quoted the safest answer. Downvoting was not really necessary

Answer (score 7):

Don't do that - look into using [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead to parametrize your queries, this is build in, i.e.:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table1 where Id = @id and Column2=@columnTwo", myConnection))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = someId;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@columnTwo", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = "You name it";
   //..
}
```

Comment: +1 - Totally agree.  You don't want to be subject to SQL-injection attacks nor have to worry about strings containing the ' character.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You should still validate input data even with parameterized queries.

Comment: But I am trying create report.So I have to find Parametrs in Query
so Users will insert the Values.

Comment: @YardimaIhtiyaciOlan: These values would be the input to the SQL parameters - see example

Answer (score 0):

No - you should `String.Format` method - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=VS.100%29.aspx